# Is it possible to write pattern-matched functions in pointfree form?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following Haskell code.

```
data Keypress = Keypress Int Char

getSeq :: Keypress -> [Char]
getSeq (Keypress i c) = replicate i c
```

**Is there any way to write `getSeq` in pointfree form?**

`getSeq`'s definition is so similar to its pattern match that it seems there might be some way to use currying or monads or something to avoid specifying the `i` and `c` parameters. However, [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) does not resolve a point-free output for `getSeq`, I think due to the pattern match.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is often useful, especially for recursive data types with multiple constructors, to define a **catamorphism**, a way to fold up a data structure when given one function for each of the possible constructors.

For example, for `Bool` the catamorphism is

```
bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a
bool x _ False = x
bool _ y True = y
```

and for `Either` it is

```
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
either f _ (Left x) = f x
either _ g (Right x) = g x
```

A more advanced catamorphism is the one for lists, which you have probably seen before: `foldr`!

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f init [] = init
foldr f init (x:xs) = f x (foldr f init xs)
```

We don't usually think of it this way (or at least I don't), but `foldr` is a catamorphism: it handles pattern-matching and recursively deconstructing the list for you, so long as you provide "handlers" for values found in the two constructors of `[a]`:

- One case to handle `[]`, needing no arguments at all: just a value of type `b`
- One case to handle `(x:xs)`. This case takes one argument representing `x`, the head of the list, and one argument representing the result of folding up the tail recursively, a value of type `b`.

A catamorphism is less exciting for a type with only one constructor, but we can easily define one for your `Keypress` type:

```
key :: (Int -> Char -> a) -> Keypress -> a
key f (Keypress x c) = f x c
```

In a way, the catamorphism allows you to abstract away the pattern-matching part of the function definition, after which you can just work with functions that don't need to touch the underlying data type directly anymore.

Having defined that generally-useful function once, you can use it many times, to implement any point-free function your heart desires. In your case, you could simply write

```
getSeq :: Keypress -> [Char]
getSeq = key replicate
```

Answer (score 13):

As written, no. But you can fix that if you want:

```
data Keypress = Keypress
  { count :: Int
  , char :: Char }
```

Then

```
getSeq p = replicate (count p) (char p)
```

and that can be converted to

```
getSeq = replicate <$> count <*> char
```

Answer (score 6):

You can’t do it without a little bit of boilerplate, but `lens` can generate that boilerplate for you, so that’s probably as close as you are going to get.

Using `makePrisms` from `Control.Lens.TH` will generate an `Iso`, which is, essentially, a first-class pattern-match on a single-constructor datatype. Conveniently, `Iso`s are bidirectional, so you can `view` them (to get values out, like pattern-matching) and `review` them (to put a value back in, like using the constructor normally).

Using `makePrisms` and `view`, it’s possible to write `getSeq` in a pointfree way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data Keypress = Keypress Int Char
makePrisms ''Keypress

getSeq :: Keypress -> [Char]
getSeq = uncurry replicate . view _Keypress
```

Is this better? No idea. The pattern-match in your code looks just fine to me, but if you’re using `lens` already anyway, this version might be more agreeable to you.